# Memory-mapped drive in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, memory, memory-management

.NET 4.0 introduced [memory-mapped files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/memory-mapped-files). Memory-mapped files can be created persistent (based on a physical file on disk) or non-persistent (not associated with a physical file).

A quick scan of the MSDN documentation didn't immediately answer whether:

- .NET supports the a memory-mapped drive or partition?
- If not, is there another mechanism or 3rd party utility that can be invoked from a C# application to create a temporary drive?

The idea would be to create (say) "M:" drive. To application code, the drive would appear and behave like a physical drive. You'd be able to create folders, read and write files, etc. I suppose the new drive might be something akin to an in-memory version of the DOS `subst` command.

Comment: https://dokan-dev.github.io/#:~:text=Dokan%20is%20a%20user%20mode,systems%20on%20Windows%20operating%20systems.

Comment: Windows ships with [ProjFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/projfs/projected-file-system), which also has [an official managed API](https://github.com/microsoft/ProjFS-Managed-API).

Answer (score 1):

Your question has nothing to do with .Net or memory mapped files. There are however plenty of ram-backed virtual drives out there, like [ImDisk](https://sourceforge.net/projects/imdisk-toolkit/), for example.

Comment: Well, its not about memory-mapped files, though I don't think that was implied. Having a look at `ImDisk` now.